# action method is not called in JSF

Tags: jsf

This is my Phase Listener

```
public class AdminPhaseListener implements PhaseListener {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -1161541721597667238L;

    public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("after Phase " + e.getPhaseId());
    }

    public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("before Phase " + e.getPhaseId());
        if(e.getPhaseId()== PhaseId.RESTORE_VIEW)
        {

        }

    }

    public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
        return PhaseId.ANY_PHASE;
    }
}
```

On click of a Command Button in my page, i call an action method and do some processing but the action method is not called at all, but in the server log , i could see the messages printed by my PhaseListener for all the Phases.

If my view was not changed, It would have stopped after the RESTORE_VIEW Phase right?

any thoughts?

Adding the code for How I display the Command Button :

```
<table width="100%">
    <h:column rendered="#{adminBean.displayResultsSize > 0}">

        <tr>
            <td colspan="14" height="5" nowrap="nowrap" class="WhiteRow"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="14" height="1" nowrap="nowrap" align="center"
                bgcolor="#999999"></td>

        </tr>
        <h:inputHidden  id="removeUserId" value="#{adminBean.removeUserId}"/>
        <h:inputHidden  id="removeIBD" value="#{adminBean.removeIBD}"/>
        <h:inputHidden  id="removeAPA" value="#{adminBean.removeAPA}"/>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="14" height="30" nowrap="nowrap"
                class="FilterColumnGrayHeader" align="center">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="button" disabled="disabled" id="button_edit"
                value="Edit Details" class="disabledfield"
                onclick="populateEditRow();">
            </input> <h:commandButton type="submit" class="disabledfield" immediate="true"
                id="button_remove" value="Remove" onclick="populateRemoveRow();" action="#{adminBean.remove}">
            </h:commandButton> &#160;

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr bgcolor="#000000">
            <td colspan="14" height="1" nowrap="nowrap" align="center"
                bgcolor="#999999"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="10"></td>
        </tr>
    </h:column>
</table>
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I'm citing from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-is-not-being-invoked/2120183#2120183):

> Whenever an `UICommand` component fails to invoke the associated action, verify the following:
>
> 1. `UICommand` components must be placed inside an `UIForm` component (e.g. `h:form`).
> 2. You cannot **nest** multiple `UIForm` components in each other (watch out with include files!).
> 3. No validation/conversion error should have been occurred (use `h:messages` to get them all).
> 4. If `UICommand` components are placed inside an `UIData` component, ensure that exactly the same `DataModel` (the object behind the `UIData`'s `value` attribute) is preserved.
> 5. The `rendered` and `disabled` attributes of the component and all of the parent components should not evaluate to `false` during apply request values phase.
> 6. Be sure that no `PhaseListener` or any `EventListener` in the request-response chain has changed the JSF lifecycle to skip the invoke action phase.
> 7. Be sure that no `Filter` or `Servlet` in the same request-response chain has blocked the request fo the `FacesServlet` somehow.

Another cause can be that you're not running the code you think you're running.

Comment: @gekrish Same for me in most cases. This can quickly happen if a view-parameter is saved loosely in a request scoped variable like: `<f:param value="#{viewValue}">` An optional flash-scope for `f:param` would be great. Else I always save it in a view-scoped bean.

Answer (score 8):

This generally means that there are validation errors on the page. Try setting `immediate="true"` to overcome the errors, or use `<h:messages>` to show the errors that arose.

Comment: Please explain how `immediate="true"` overcomes errors which occur without it. What happens with the reasons for the errors?

Comment: This answer saved me after hours of search. Thanks, @Bozho!

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is an error being generated on any setter of your components.