# Form not submitting on a page with fragment 'rendered' conditions and ui:param

Tags: jsf, form-submit, java-ee-7

I'm creating a some sort of online shop with JSF. I have a `product.xhtml` page that displays the product by ID. I'm passing that ID as a param (.../product.xhtml?id=3) and I'm getting the ID with `<ui:param name="productID" value="#{request.getParameter('id')}" />`

That all works well.

Next, I'm **showing** and **hiding** certain elements in the page with `<f:subview>` (I've used `<ui:fragment>` before). The reason is that if the user deletes the `?id=3` ID parameter, the page will show an error (eg. code `<f:subview id="main" rendered="#{productID != null and productID != ''}">`). Another reason is that if the product belongs to the buyer, the BUY button will not appear and if the user is not authenticated the BUY button will not appear.

The problem is with the BUY button. It is in a form and the action of the button is just a simple test method (for now) from the CDI bean that prints something to the server console and redirects the user. **Unfortunately**, this does not work. The page (`/product.xhtml`) gets reloaded with no ID param.

I've tried several things like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045129/how-to-call-an-action-method-of-a-uicommand-component-which-was-rendered-conditi) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981077/form-submit-does-not-trigger-action-method-on-managedbean-on-a-jsf-1-2-page-with) and nothing is working.

I've tried using the `ViewScoped` and `SessionScoped` for my CDI bean instead of RequestScoped, but that does nothing. The `ViewScoped` fails to build.

I've also changed the `<ui:fragment>` to `<f:subview>`

Here's some code..

**CDI bean controller**

```java
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class ProductManager {
    ...
    public String buy(Product product) {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        try {
            HttpSession session = Util.getSession();
            User buyer = (User)session.getAttribute("user");

            Date date = new Date();

            System.out.println("TEST DATA: ");
            System.out.println("sale product: "+product.getTitle());
            System.out.println("sale buyer:   "+buyer.getUsername());
            System.out.println("sale date:    "+date);
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            System.err.println("ProductManager#buy -> "+ex.getMessage());
        }
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "An error occured", null));
        return "index";
    }
    ...
}
```

**Products.xhtml**

```html
...
<ui:param name="productID" value="#{request.getParameter('id')}" />
...
<f:subview id="buyBtn" rendered="#{user.username != login.username and login.regUser}">
    <h:form style="margin-top: 30px;">
        <b:navCommandLink styleClass="btn btn-info btn-block" disabled="#{!product.status}" value="Buy" action="#{productManager.buy(product)}"></b:navCommandLink>
    </h:form>
</f:subview>
...
```

I can provide full code if needed.

What I'm expecting the code to do is that whenever I click on the BUY button, I'll get redirected to my page and the TEST DATA will be printed on server console.

Comment: So it works with JSF2.1? Or on Tomcat? And also if you don't use BootsFaces? Cause that is what your tagging implies. Tags are not for what you use, but for what is part of the problem (=removing it or using another version solves it)

Comment: I've changed now. Better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many. many attempts I solved this. I cannot find the exact explanation, as I read a ton of articles on this topic.

I used [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org/). Next in `products.xhtml` I changed `h:form` to [o:form](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/form) (from OmniFaces) and have these two set to true `includeRequestParams="true" includeViewParams="true"`. My bean then became `org.omnifaces.cdi.ViewScoped`

[This](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2010/06/benefits-and-pitfalls-of-viewscoped.html) is also a great article