# Conditionally rendered command link does not invoke action

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf

I have an `<af:commandLink>` and a `<h:panelGrid>`. The link is outside the grid. On page load I am keeping `rendered="false"` on the grid. I also have another link inside the grid. So this link is not rendered since the grid is not rendered. On click of the link outside the grid I am setting `rendered="true"` and thus the link inside the grid is also rendered.

Now, when I then click the link inside the grid, the action is not invoked. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

```
<af:commandLink action="#{masterFileConfig.getMasterFileTypeConfig}" onclick="return requiredCheck();"
                binding="#{masterFileConfig.commandLink1}"
                id="commandLink1">
    <af:objectImage source="/images/search.gif"
                    binding="#{masterFileConfig.objectImage1}"
                    id="objectImage1"/>
</af:commandLink>
<h:panelGrid columns="2" binding="#{masterFileConfig.panelGrid2}" rendered="#{masterFileConfig.showGrid}"
             id="panelGrid2" width="100%" styleClass="greyTable">
    <h:panelGrid columns="1" border="0" 
                 id="panelGrid3" width="100%" style="text-align:right;">
        <af:commandLink action="#{masterFileConfig.saveMasterFileTypeConfig}"
                        onclick="return handleBusinessRules();"
                        id="commandLink2">
            <af:objectImage source="/images/save.gif" id="objectImage2"/>
        </af:commandLink>
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:panelGrid>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call an action method of a UICommand Component which was rendered conditionally?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045129/how-to-call-an-action-method-of-a-uicommand-component-which-was-rendered-conditi)

Comment: Thanks Balus. Can you please elaborate on your comments: 3.If you're using <h:commandLink> instead of <h:commandButton>, then you can use <f:param> to transfer the property. It will be available as request parameter, you can check for it in bean's (post)constructor.

Possibly a code sample would be of great help.

Comment: thanks Balus.. i used the following stuff of one of the users and it worked  --> In my case, Javascript came for rescue, Which means, whatever was to be displayed conditionally , put them in a HTML Portion and don't display them display: none until the desired event occurs.

HTML Portion can have any JSF Tags(including CommandButtons) as you wish and would work (invoking the action methods and the stuff )perfectly okay.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try and set the clientComponent property of your link to true? Maybe there is no client component generated for the onClick event to interact with.

Also - have you considered using the af:commandImageLink instead of two components?