# h:command link not executed

Tags: ajax, jsf, commandlink

I have a datatable in my jsf page and I need to have an index for this table. In this index I have links like as follows :

```
<h:commandLink value="2 " action="#{index.findByCat()}">
  <f:param name="tpage" value="10"></f:param>
  <f:param name="cat" value="#{index.cat}"></f:param>
  <f:ajax render=":tg"></f:ajax>
</h:commandLink>
```

But the method defined as action is not executed when I click the link.

Comment: Is there a form? Also show the action method definition.

Comment: yes the command link is nested in a <h:form> tag. I don't think the method definition would be requried. you can imagine a method containing System.out.println("executed"); . But the problem is here that th method is not executed.

Comment: Well if the method looks like `public String findByCat()`, I have no clue why it isn't called. Validation or conversion error on some field of the same form?

Comment: no, no errors or exceptions !

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3044738/354831) answer could help you...